# Does Vert.x support the operation of converting asynchronous results to synchronous ones?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, vert.x, blocking, completable-future

I have a method with a synchronous return value, but it internally calls an asynchronous operation.

Now I use ".toCompletionStage().toCompletableFuture().get". But I have encountered blocked thread problems. I am very confused and suspect it's related to the thread pool. Who can help me explain this?

```
public String load(){
    
     Future<String> future = /* sample code return future*/;
     String data = future.toCompletionStage().toCompletableFuture().get();
     return data;
}
```

```
vertx.consumer("topic", req->{
     String data = load();
     req.reply(data);
}
```

When I request the "topic", it will block eventloop thread.

Comment: Exception:   WARN  [vertx-blocked-thread-checker] io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker  - Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-4,5,main] has been blocked for 5569735 ms, time limit is 2000 ms

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: No.** "Converting" a `Future` would mean to block execution until the result is available. And that's against Vert.x No. 1 rule - [never block the event loops](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_dont_block_me).

Reason for this is that an event loop has only one thread to deal all I/O events. If you block it, all other events (requests, file system operations etc.) will need to wait.

That's why `vertx-blocked-thread-checker` is unhappy and warns you, so you have a chance to fix the issue.

The `load` method in your example should just return `Future<String>`. That way, you defer processing of `load()`'s result until it is available. All calling methods will have to adapt and also **work with or return** `Future`. If that seems strange, there are many discussions about *function coloring* out there...

`load()` should look like this:

```java
public Future<String> load() {
  return /* sample code return future*/
}
```

And the call site should look like this:

```java
vertx.consumer("topic", req -> {
     load().onSuccess(data -> req.reply(data));
});
```

Note how the code declares now what needs to be done *after the result is available*.